# Writing a CSS or Xpath as a one element

Tags: testing, xpath, css-selectors

```
`<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Preeti</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Preeti</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>2</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>`
```

I want to write CSS or Xpath selector, for the above code where The Output should be "Preeti 2", the catch is that the "Preeti" should come from the First  tag, and "2" should be from the 2nd  tag. The CSS or Xpath for the above should be in a single line.
For Example:
tagname#value,tagname#value [here two CSS are combined in one line] similarly want to do the above but don't know how.

Comment: so, something like `"table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) div,table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) div"`

Comment: What about, _string-join(table/tr[1]/td[1]/div | table/tr[2]/td[2]/div, ' ')_

Comment: That is not code, it is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/concat) to combine the content of both `td`s in the second `tr`:

```
concat(/table/tr[2]/td[1]/div, /table/tr[2]/td[2]/div)
```

---

JavaScript example:

```js
<script>
const html = `<table>...</table>`
const doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(html, "application/xml")
const xpath = "concat(/table/tr[2]/td[1]/div, /table/tr[2]/td[2]/div)"
const result = doc.evaluate(xpath, doc)
console.log(result.stringValue)
</script>
```

---

If the document is a parsed HTML5 DOM however, `table` won't be the root element, so you might need a slightly different XPath expression to skip the `table`'s ancestors (`//table/…`). You also have to consider HTML5 `tbody` elements appearing, so the expression would be:

```
concat(//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div, //table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div)"
```

see [JSFilddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0s14r58/)